# How to realign column headers with the respective rows after importing a csv data set

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook, data-cleaning

I tried to load data from a csv file but i can't seem to be able to re-align the column headers to the respective rows for a clearer data frame.

Below is the output of

`df.head()`

```
bookID,title,authors,average_rating,isbn,isbn13,language_code,# num_pages,ratings_count,text_reviews_count
```

0   1,Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince (Harr...
1   2,Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix (H...
2   3,Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone (Harry...
3   4,Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets (Har...
4   5,Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban (Ha...

```
import pandas as pd

file = 'C:/Users/user/Documents/Temporary data sets for practise only/books.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(file, sep ='/t')

df.head()
```

[Ref](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoxuK.png)

Answer (score 1):

You've set '\t' as your delimiter value while your document extract shows commas between the columns. Try

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, sep =',')
```

or just

```
pd.read_csv(file)
```

since ',' is the standard delimiter.

Comment: I've tried that but it returns below error.  'ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 10 fields in line 4012, saw 11'

Comment: Try to specify the columns by using `df = pd.read_csv(file, sep =',', usecols=[col_1, col_2, ..., col_n])`

Comment: This works thank you. However, what if i have a dataset that has 100 columns.Will i have to type all the cols or is there a simpler, shorter way?